# Keyboard/typing problems on Dell laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, keyboard, dell-inspiron, typing

I've started to notice all kinds of typing/keyboard issues on my laptop recently (Dell Inspiron n5110). Some of them are:

- when I wake the laptop from sleep, I can't type my password
- can't type to search for items (WIN 8.1)
- the position of some characters when I'm using my Serbian keyboard seems to randomly change
- "Turn on Sticky Keys" message pops out with no apparent reason

Some of these issues go away when I restart the computer, and they don't necessarily all happen at the same time, or each time I turn on my computer.

As I said, I'm using Windows 8.1 and have recently flashed my BIOS (in hopes that it would help to upgrade to Windows 10).

If anyone has any ideas on what the source of all this could be (because they seem to be connected and similar), I'd be grateful for a piece of advice.

**Note:** currently I can type normally in Notepad, my browser etc. BUT can't type on the start screen to search for files (even typing in the search box on the start screen doesn't work).

Comment: Have you reverted your BIOS back to the previous version to see if that is the cause? Also, have you tried an external keyboard to determine if it is an issue with the keyboard itself or a system issue?

Comment: @CharlieRB External keyboard has the exact same problems. I saw many people writing that Sticky Keys/Filter Keys were causing similar issues, but that doesn't seem to be my case because the problems persist after turning those features off. I guess reverting to the old BIOS should be my next step.

Comment: Yes, revert the BIOS. If the problem goes away, you have found the cause.